# Dynamically set font-weight and style in FabricJS5

Tags: fabricjs

FabricJS API seems to have change and `obj.set("fontWeight", "bold");` doesn't work anymore.

How can I change the fontWeight of a text **after** its creation?
`obj` here is `this.canvas.getActiveObject()`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to set it as object.

```
obj.set({fontWeight: "bold"});
```

See more at fabricJS [docs](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Text.html#set).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).